# Tulu temple priests in kerala

Tags: temple, worship, agamas

Though Kerala was sankaracharyas bhoomi, many priests in temples earlier we're selected from madhwa tulu lands. These were directly done by rajas of cochin and travancore including many temples in ernakulam. What could be the reason for the same